# Camel - RoutePolicy - ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy does not work with multiple consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

In our application, we are using kafka component to consume messages off kafka topic in manual commit mode. In cases we encounter a exception on the subsequent process ( external service call failures - throws RetryableException) , we had wired in ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy to open the circuit and retry the circuit close based on a HalfOpenHandler, a RetryableException is encountered.

ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy {
throttledException - RetryableException,
failureThreshold - 1,
failureWindow = 1 mins
halfOpenAfter - x mins
keepOpen = false
}

from("kafka:topicName").routePolicy(exceptionPolicy).to(anotherProcess);

When we run single consumer per pod, the circuit open/close is working as expected. But in case of multiple consumers, the circuit is open but the circuit close is not attempted.

Looking at the ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy code:

Both 1st and 2nd consumer threads are waiting for acquiring the lock.

1. Thread T1 acquires the lock and the thread T2 is waiting.
2. consumer stopped, STATE is OPEN , policy.openedAt - t1, halfOpenTask(h1) scheduled to run after x (threshold) ms, policy.halfOpenTimer => h1
3. lock is released
4. Thread T2 acquires the lock.
5. consumer has already stopped, STATE is still OPEN , policy.openedAt = t2 ( t2 > t1) , halfOpenTask (h2 - new instance) scheduled to run after x ms. policy.halfOpenTimer => h2.
6. All this time h1 timer is counting down. Once the timer completes, the HalfOpen task is queued and started.
7. Within the HalfOpen task's run method ->
   7.a  cancel policy.halfOpenTimer (h2)
   7.b  so h2 half-open scheduled task is cancelled
   7.c  invoke this.calculateState()

   ```
           7.c.1  check the state is OPEN and if elapsedTime >= threshold X  , then call half-open handler
                  but the  elapsedTime is currentTs (t1+x) - openedAt(t2) so the condition is never 
                  true. So the half-open handler is never called.
   ```

This might happen to any camel route with concurrent consumers > 1.

Did anyone run into similar issues ?

Answer (score 0):

It happens with one concurrentConsumers=1 as well
with the concurrencyLimit: 50
apparently timer never close the circuit. thiss is the last statement getting logged.
2021-08-04 15:56:59.473 DEBUG 99845 --- [askExecutor-104] o.a.c.t.ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy   : Opening circuit...

also, ThrottlingExceptionRoutePolicy.failures just keep incremented beyond the failureWindow.

```
    protected boolean isThresholdExceeded() {
    boolean output = false;
    this.logState();
    if (this.failures.get() >= this.failureThreshold && this.lastFailure >= System.currentTimeMillis() - this.failureWindow) {
        output = true;
    }

    return output;
}
```

the "output" will be true as long as failures >= failureThreshold (which will be at some point) and the lastFailure happened within the failureWindow.
failures will not set unless closeCircuit is called. That's a bug.